# How to join the edges of one line layer to nearest line layer and deleting the extra line after the intersection point in pyqgis?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Hi all im a newbie to the qgis and pyqgis, as i mentioned in the question i have two condtions:

Condition 1:[image]

I want result something like this[image]

condition 2:[image]

i want something like this [image]

Basically i want to match the edge of two shapefiles i tried creating start point and endpoint and shortest line between them but it didn't help me.

I will be thankful if anyone guide me how to solve this . Thank You

Answer (score 0):

My English is not very good, but I can provide the idea of ​​what I did before
Algorithms require you to write your own

1. The line is actually composed of several points
   So you need to find the head and tail coordinates of the line is a list[0] and list[-1]
2. You need to write code to calculate the distance between two coordinates and change the coordinates of the line attributes
   Iterate over each coordinate using the coordinates of list[0] and list[-1]
   Assuming that the coordinates of list[0] and line B are the closest, modify the coordinates of lineB to list[0]

Finally, some parts need to be corrected. For example, you need to exclude the coordinate comparison with the other end of the line.
Hope it helps you